# Extjs Ext rownumberer column not able to do mouse hover

Tags: extjs

Extjs Ext rownumberer column not able to do mouse hover.

The mouse hover happened all the column except that rownumberer column. Can you please help me o this?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xO9qM.png)

https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3nm1

Comment: I have fixed this issue now. Thanks

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.